# Is it possible to make Doorkeeper to ignore basic auth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, doorkeeper

I am trying to protect my swagger with Basic Auth. But also, the Doorkeeper with Bearer authentication is used.

If I send the basic and bearer in one query, doorkeeper doesn't authorize me.

Is it possible to make doorkeeper ignore basic auth and only accept Bearer?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you can try to play with `client_credentials` and `access_token_methods` configuration options and set desired way of getting authorization data from the request.

You can find more info in project wiki, [Changing how clients are authenticated](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/wiki/Changing-how-clients-are-authenticated) (but it actually a stale one), or check the configuration initializer (in your project or in [Doorkeeper repo](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/blob/master/lib/generators/doorkeeper/templates/initializer.rb#L184-L198))